# Ajax request Complex type is getting null in a ApiController parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and trying to create a page. My page is having a search area and grid view with a paging.

PagerModel model is the common model to contain paging details.

Product page search model and pager model

```
public class ProductSearchModel
{       
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> Clients { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
    
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> Stores { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();

    public string Title { get; set; }       
    public string Sku { get; set; }
  
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> Vendors { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
   
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> ProductTypes { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();

    public PagerModel PagingModel { get; set; } = new PagerModel();
}

public class PagerModel
{
    public int PageTotal { get; set; }
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int PagingButtonCount { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PagesCount { get; set; }
    public bool ShowTotalSummary { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Ajax request; I also tried using `JSON.stringify(postData)`, but it's still not working:

```
function fetchData(pageNumber) {
    var $loading = "<div class='loading'>Please wait...</div>";
    $('#updatePanel').prepend($loading);

    var clientId = $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.ClientId)").val();
    var storeId = $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.StoreId)").val();
    var title = $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.Title)").val();
    var sku = $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.Sku)").val();
    var productType = $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.ProductType)").val();
    var vendor = $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.Vendor)").val();
    var pageSize = @Model.PagingModel.PageSize;
    var postData = {
                    clientId: parseInt(clientId),
                    storeId: parseInt(storeId),
                    title: title,
                    sku: sku,
                    productType: productType,
                    vendor: vendor,
                    pagingModel: {
                        pageNumber: pageNumber,
                        pageIndex: (pageNumber - 1),
                        pageSize: pageSize
                    }
            };
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url:  "@(Url.Action("PopulateProductGrid", "Products"))",                
                data: postData,//JSON.stringify(postData),
                success: function (data) {
     

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
}
```

This is the `ProductController` action method. I have tried without `[FromBody]`, but it's not working:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PopulateProductGrid([FromBody] ProductSearchModel searchModel)
{
    var productModel = GetProducts(searchModel);

    var data = new { 
                       Product = productModel.Products, 
                       TotalPage = productModel.PagerModel.PageTotal, 
                       PagesCount = productModel.PagerModel.PagesCount, 
                       PagingButtonCount = productModel.PagerModel.PagingButtonCount 
                   };

    return Json(data);
}
```

Comment: *try* removing `contentType: 'application/json',` - remove `contentType` completely

Answer (score 0):

Fix your ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                 url: "/Products/PopulateProductGrid",                
                data: postData,
                success: function (data) {
     
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
```

if it still is not working then fix your data too:

remove parseint

```
  clientId: clientId,
   storeId: storeId,
....
```

and make your data syntax more simple, for example replace your clientId with this

```
 var clientId = $("#clientId").val();
// and so on for another data controls
```

if you dont have ids in your view controls then add them.